# Analyzing the variance of an outcome variable: modelling standard deviation/sigma itself

Tags: regression, bayesian, variance, standard-deviation, hierarchical-bayesian

Is the following a correct approach for sigma modelling?

Let’s assume we have a Y variable named hours in lognormal scale. We would like to know how these hours changed in time (variable named year).

**Data**

```
set.seed(0)
pi <- 0
mu_log <- 2
sigma_log <- 0.99
N = 1000
hours = (1 - rbinom(N, 1, prob = pi)) * rlnorm(N, mu_log, sigma_log)
year = seq(1,10, 1)
df = data.frame(hours=hours, year=year)
```

**Model (using [brms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html) package)**

```
m = brm(bf(hours ~ year, sigma ~ year), data = df, family = lognormal())
```

**Summary**

```
Family: lognormal
Links: mu = identity; sigma = log
Formula: hours ~ year
sigma ~ year
Data: df (Number of observations: 1000)
Samples: 4 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
total post-warmup samples = 4000

Population-Level Effects: 
                Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept           2.06      0.07     1.92     2.19 1.00     3742     2379
sigma_Intercept    -0.01      0.05    -0.10     0.09 1.00     5050     3068
year               -0.01      0.01    -0.03     0.01 1.00     4144     2783
sigma_year         -0.00      0.01    -0.02     0.02 1.00     5213     3302
```

**Temporal trend for mean hours**

```
m %>% conditional_effects()
```

[image]

**Temporal trend for the standard deviation of hours?**

```
 m %>% conditional_effects(dpar = “sigma”)
```

[image]

**Can we say that the standard deviation of hours did not change during the observed years, meaning that variation remained unchanged? And am I correct that these hours on the sigma plot is on the original scale of Y variable(hours)?**